# Dynamically pulling data from sheet to a sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, template-engine

I am trying to retrieve data from another sheet (within the same spreadsheet) and display it as a dropdown option in the sidebar.

My code.gs has function called `getVisualData()` which correctly returns the list I want.

```
function getVisualData(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getRangeByName('VISUAL_TYPES')
  .getValues()
  .flat()
  .filter(vs => vs != '')
}
```

In my HTML file, I tried calling this function and looping through it displaying each index but with no success

```html
 <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="visual_type" name="visual_type" required>
      <? const visuals = getVisualData(); ?>
      <? visuals.forEach( vs => { ?> 
      <option value='<?= vs ?>'> <?= vs ?> </option>
      <? }) ; ?>
 </select>
```

I tried using Scriptlets but am unsure if I can inject the variable vs into the options tag. Currently, my dropdown displays this string

```html
<?= vs ?>
```

Comment: What happens with your code? Does it work? What are you actually asking? If it's working please add a [mcve] (include sample data, the HtmlService statement, the resulting HTML, etc.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was clear in the text. The dropdown displays the string "<?= vs ?>"  exactly as it is and not any of the values in the list visuals.

Comment: Show the code that creates the sidebar's `HtmlOutput` object. If you don't idea of what I talking about, please read http://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details directly into the question body.

Comment: No change was done to the question ... so no, the question is not clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

I made no changes to your code and used the following function to launch a dialog which worked just fine.

gs:

```
function launchMyDialog() {
  let h = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ah2").evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(h,"my dialog");
}

function getVisualData(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getRangeByName('VISUAL_TYPES')
  .getValues()
  .flat()
  .filter(vs => vs != '');
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="visual_type" name="visual_type" required>
      <? const visuals = getVisualData(); ?>
      <? visuals.forEach( vs => { ?> 
      <option value='<?= vs ?>'> <?= vs ?> </option>
      <? }) ; ?>
 </select>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I did it with a sidebar as well.  Works okay.

My data was just a column of numbers.

Comment: Strange. It must lie somewhere else. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Did you create a template and then evaluate it?